# Why does the reverse() function not work when passed along with list in numpy.array()?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reverse

I have to write a function that returns a reversed Numpy Array with element type `float` from a list.

```
>>>myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>myList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I used the `reverse()` function *while* passing the list to the `numpy.array()` function like so:

```
>>>def arrays(someList):
       return numpy.array(someList.reverse(), float)
```

But this returns an empty array:

```
>>>arrays(myList)
array(nan)
```

However, if I reverse the list using `reverse()` before passing it, it works alright.

```
>>>def arrays(someList):
       someList.reverse()
       return numpy.array(someList, float)

>>>arrays(myList)
array([5.,  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.])
```

On the contrary, if I use the `list[::-1]` technique to reverse the list in the same place as I had used the `reverse()` function the first time, it works like a charm.

```
>>>def arrays(someList):
       return numpy.array(someList[::-1] , float)

>>>arrays(myList)
array([5.,  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.])
```

Although my code works alright, I want to understand why the first way of using `reverse()` doesn't work with the `numpy.array()` function.

Thanks!

Edit 1: Sorry I meant `numpy.array(someList.reverse(), float)` and not `numpy.array(someList, reverse(), float)

Comment: Did you mean to write `return numpy.array(someList.reverse(), float)`?

Comment: What `reverse()` function? There's no `reverse` either built-in or in NumPy. Where's the `reverse()` in `numpy.array(someList, reverse(), float)` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Sorry I meant `someList.reverse()` and not `someList, reverse()`. I've made the edit.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for pointing me in the right direction. I somehow couldn't find that question when I was searching prior to posting my question.